# Sheaf of regular functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am trying to show that if $X$ is an (irreducible) affine variety, then $O_X$, which is the set of rings $O_X(U)$ of regular functions on open subsets of $X$, with the obvious restriction maps, is really a sheaf. I am able to verify that

- $\rho_{U,U}$ is the identity
- for any inclusion $U\subset V\subset W$, we have $\rho_{V,U}\circ\rho_{W,V}=\rho_{W,U}$.

Also, I can show the glueing property. However, I can't show that $\mathcal{F}(\emptyset)=0$. How would the definition work, seeing that
$$\mathcal{F}(\emptyset)=O_X(\emptyset)=\bigcap_{P\in\emptyset}O_{X,P}.$$

So how does one show that $\mathcal{F}(\emptyset)=0$?

Comment: What is the exact definition of $O_X$ you're using?

Comment: @EricWofsey $X$ is an affine variety. $O_X$ is the set of rings $O_X(U)$ of regular functions on open subsets of $X$. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to be irreducible (sometimes that is included in the definition of "variety", sometimes it is not)?  Otherwise, that formula for $O_X$ looks problematic even for nonempty sets.

Comment: @EricWofsey i'm taking it to be irreducible.

Comment: What exactly are regular functions for you? How many functions are there $\emptyset\to k$? There is exactly one. Does the definittion of regularity apply to it?

Comment: What is your definition of "regular function"?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez There is only one function $\emptyset\to k$. A regular function on $U$ is a rational function that is well-defined at all points of $U$.

Comment: Well, is the one function $\emptyset\to k$ regular according to that definition?

Comment: (When you ask questions about algebraic geometry like this one, which is more or less about definitions, you should specify xactly what definitions you are using, or what textbook you are following, for there are several different approaches to all of this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your definition of regular functions ("A regular function on $U$ is a rational function that is well-defined at all points of $U$"), they indeed do not form a sheaf, as $O_X(\emptyset)$ is the entire field of rational functions on $X$, rather than $0$.  An easy (if inelegant) way to fix this is to say that your definition is only the definition of a regular function on a *nonempty* open subset of $X$, and by definition the ring of regular functions on the empty set is $0$.

There are various more elegant definitions that achieve this same result.  For instance, a commonly used definition is that a regular function on $U$ is a function $\varphi:U\to k$ such that there exists a rational function $f\in K(X)$ which is regular at each point of $U$ and such that $\varphi(P)=f(P)$ for each $P\in U$.  By this definition, the formula $O_X(U)=\bigcap_{P\in U} O_{X,P}$ for $U$ nonempty becomes a somewhat nontrivial theorem, and it is false if $U$ is the empty set.  For by this definition, a regular function on the empty set is first and foremost a function $\varphi:\emptyset\to k$, and there is only one such function (even though there are many different $f\in K(X)$ such that $\varphi(P)=f(P)$ for all $P\in \emptyset$!).  So $O_X(\emptyset)$ is a ring with one element, i.e. the zero ring.

Comment: His definition is that a function is regular if is a function to the field and it is regular; the equality he wrote with the intersection, on the other hand, only works in the nonempty case.

Comment: That's not how I read his comment...but maybe I misinterpreted it.

Comment: he probably meant: the restriction of a rational function regular at all points of $U$.

Comment: Actually, that (the second paragraph) was the way I wanted to define the regular function but thought I lacked space in the comments. Thanks for the answer though!